# Using choco solver for solving equations

Tags: java, api, constraints, smt, choco

I am looking for a way to encode mathematical equations on Choco Solver.
I see there's a way to encode constraints like:

x + y < 9

But I am trying to encode something like

3x + 4y < 9

where x and y are int vars.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to Choco but I can solve this one.

To do that you can use the constraint `scalar` (see [docs](http://choco-solver.org/apidocs/org/chocosolver/solver/constraints/IntConstraintFactory.html#scalar-org.chocosolver.solver.variables.IntVar:A-int:A-java.lang.String-org.chocosolver.solver.variables.IntVar-)).

First you just need to define the `x` and the `y` in two `IntVar` variables. You can use `VariableFactory.bounded` or `Variable.enumerated`. They are pretty similar when you just want to use a domain with a lower bound and an upper bound, but the difference is explained in the [user guide](http://choco-solver.org/user_guide/2_modelling.html#enumerated-variable).

Then you need to define an array with the coefficients of the equation, in this case `{ 3, 4 }`.

Here is how you do it:

```
Solver solver = new Solver();

IntVar x = VariableFactory.bounded("x", 0, 50, solver);
IntVar y = VariableFactory.bounded("y", 0, 50, solver);

int[] coefficients = new int[]{ 3, 4 };

solver.post(IntConstraintFactory.scalar(new IntVar[]{ x,  y }, coefficients, "<", VariableFactory.fixed(9, solver)));

if (solver.findSolution()) {
    do {
        System.out.println("x = " + x.getValue() + ", y = " + y.getValue());
    } while (solver.nextSolution());
} else {
    System.out.println("The equation has no solutions.");
}
```